Que libreria para generar PDF en typescript me recomiendan?
Estoy haciendo una rest-api con hono dev y bun js. Y pues necesito generar un informe en pdf con ciertos datos. Sin embargo, no estoy seguro de cual librería podría ser apropiada para el framework. Es mi primera vez haciendo este tipo de apps, agradecería mucho sus recomendaciones.

Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.
